# What is the default pixel size of text in HTML?

Tags: html

If I have a text like `<div> Hello Friends </div>` with a background color of red, what would be the height of this red area in pixels?

I want to know to make certain calculations for CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The height depends on the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Developer's console on Chrome? (F12 on Windows, cmd+alt+i on OSX).
You can easily right click and select "Inspect" on any element and in the bottom of all the information you have the schematics with sizes.
Here:

[image]

Comment: Note there are different heights related to inline elements: the height of the inline box, the height of the line box, and the height of the content area of the inline box. Not sure what the height in devtools refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you have

```css
span { background: red; }
```

```html
<span>Hello Friends</span>
```

and you want to know the height of the red rectangle.

According to [CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced), it's implementation dependent:

> The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this
>   specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or
>   the maximum ascender and descender of the font. (The latter would
>   ensure that glyphs with parts above or below the em-box still fall
>   within the content area, but leads to differently sized boxes for
>   different fonts; the former would ensure authors can control
>   background styling relative to the 'line-height', but leads to glyphs
>   painting outside their content area.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but the default font size for the `<p></p>` tag is 13.3px but that is the only one I know though.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the tag element you used to write the text.

Some tags and their default browser pixel measurements:

p tag - 16px

h1 tag - 32px

h2 tag - 24px